# $XY$ minus $YX$ is always divisible by $3$

Tags: divisibility

Why a $2$-digit decimal number minus the same number with the digits reversed is always divisible by $3$ ?

Comment: hint: what is the digit sum of the difference?

Comment: Hint: instead of XY write $10x+y$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We write: $XY=10X+Y, YX=10Y+X$. Hence

$XY-YX=10(X-Y)-(X-Y)=9(X-Y)$.

Your turn !

Comment: thanks for taking time for help

Answer (score 4):

Note that $`XY\text{'}$ is convenient shorthand for $10X + Y$. For example, $93$ is shorthand for $10 \cdot 9 + 3$.

So
$$
`XY\text{'} - `YX\text{'} = (10 X + Y) - (10Y + X) = 9X - 9Y = 9(X - Y),
$$
which is divisible by $9$ and in particular by $3$.

A great example of the power of simple algebra :)